# Stack overflow in REGEX search in VS2008

Tags: regex, visual-studio, cobol

I am trying to find in a huge COBOL file if all the "IF" have a corresponding "END-IF".
Using Visual Studio 2008 as I know it has a search tool with a regex feature. (Though, I know after reading Jeff Atwood's article about it, that the regex in Visual Studio are not quite the same than the real deal.)

Anyway, I came up with this expression:

```
<(IF)#(.*\n*)#END-IF\n
```

That seems to overflow the stack, quite inconveniently (see picture below).
So I was wondering, if it was at all possible to do this kind of search in VS ? 
And if it is, what would the regex look like ?

> -->I want to know if all "IF" have a closing "END-IF"

Thanks.

[image: stack overflow during regex search in VS2008]

Comment: Stack overflow in StackOverflow! This is ironic )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a case of trying to perform recursive parsing with a regular expression, and generally that's going to get you into trouble.
As I read it (granted, I am not familiar with the flavor used by Visual Studio here), your regex tries to match as many lines as it can until it finds an END-IF -- including matching another END-IF.
In other words, when presented with

```
IF condition-1
    statement-1
END-IF
IF condition-2
    statement-2
END-IF
```

one match is found, not two.

Also, think about how you want to deal with this case:

```
IF condition-1
    IF condition-2
        statement-1
    END-IF
END-IF
```

Unless you are trying to write your own language translator or COBOL lint tool, I think you can content yourself that the compiler will find your matching END-IFs, or flag an unclosed IF at the end of a paragraph.